# Missing styles on Jekyll website deployed on GitHub Pages (likely cache issues)

Tags: caching, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to deploy a Jekyll website for my [Github project](https://github.com/Faeq-F/Quokka). The code for the website is found in the `gh-pages` branch.

When deployed on `localhost`, the page looks as intended but on Github Pages it is missing a lot of styles (and possibly other resources). The Console of the deployed website is filled with 404 errors.

Here is a screenshot of the website on localhost:

[image: localhost]

Here is a screenshot of the [deployed website](https://faeq-f.github.io/Quokka/):

[image: gh-pages]

The errors in the console are as follows:

```
GET https://faeq-f.github.io/styles/Plugins.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Quokka/:56 
        
        
       GET https://faeq-f.github.io/styles/FAQ.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Quokka/:59 
        
        
       GET https://faeq-f.github.io/styles/Documentation.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Quokka/:398 
        
        
       GET https://faeq-f.github.io/scripts/Gallery.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Quokka/:402 
        
        
       GET https://faeq-f.github.io/scripts/Docs.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
header.js:51 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')
    at header.js:51:20
```

I have previously deployed a similar site [here](https://faeq-f.github.io/) on Github Pages without any issues so this issue seems pretty random.

While searching online, I found that cache might be the culprit. However, clearing the browser cache does not help. An answer I found suggested it was due to GitHub's DNS cache and as a result I started to use links like the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/DarkTheme.css?{{site.time | date: '%s%N'}}" />
```

This too did not help. I have tried other solutions like changing the GitHub-pages branch and un-publishing the site but nothing has worked.

#### Edit (5 Jan 2023) :

I have tried using a `_includes` file which has absolute links to the styles on `raw.githubusercontent.com` but this does not work as well.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Update your [github pages gem](https://github.com/github/pages-gem) to the latest version and try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55080320/17627866).

Comment: I had a couple issues with Jekyll but eventually fixed them and updated the gems. The solution doesn't seem to work and breaks viewing the page on localhost; the live version still uses the old styles like the screenshot above, whereas the localhost view loads none of the css

Comment: What errors are you seeing in console?

Comment: There are no errors relating to the problem, just to bad JS I know about. I don't expect errors as the CSS files are linked correctly to the HTML file. The issue is that it is the old CSS that is being loaded - when you go into developer tools, the Style editor tab shows that none of the edits I have made to the CSS are there, even though they appear on GitHub

Comment: As for localhost, again no errors in the console, but in the terminal window from which I am running jekyll serve, I did get not found errors. I have now fixed all of them but one. Fixing them is really confusing as the links don't seem to make sense.The link left to fix is in Gallery.js and is "../PluginScreenshots/InitialScreenshots.html". It looks for the file at http://localhost:4000/PluginScreenshots/InitialScreenshots.html. If I change the link to "PluginScreenshots/InitialScreenshots.html", it looks for the file in the same place.

Comment: If I change the link again to "Quokka/PluginScreenshots/InitialScreenshots.html", it looks for the file at http://localhost:4000/Quokka/Quokka/PluginScreenshots/InitialScreenshots.html. (The page is at http://localhost:4000/Quokka/ and I have not pushed these changes to GitHub yet)

Comment: I have a similar link in Docs.js which works; "./DocumentationCards/InitialCards.html". DocumentationCards and PluginScreenshots are on the same level of the folder hierarchy - so again it makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is mainly a file path issue. When your jekyll website is bundled, the file directory structure is not the same as your current structure. Take a look at the `_site` folder generated to see what the final structure looks like:

[image]

`_layouts/home.html` becomes the `_sites/index.html`.

In `_layouts/home.html`, to reference a stylesheet:

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/About.css" /> <!--WRONG-->

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/About.css" /> <!--Correct-->
```

Therefore the correct `home.html` file is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <![endif]-->
<html lang="en">
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Quokka</title>
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="A customizable keystroke launcher with plugins"
    />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Resources/SearchIcon.png" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Scroll library-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/studio-freight/lenis@1.0.29/bundled/lenis.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/Main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/About.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/Plugins.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/header.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/home.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/gradButtons.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/DarkTheme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/FAQ.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/Documentation.css" />
    <!--Used to fix github pages dns cache issues-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="top">
      <p style="color: transparent">.</p>
    </div>

    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">
        You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please
        <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.
      </p>
    <![endif]-->

    <header id="header" class="hidemee">
      <nav>
        <ul class="navbar">
          <li class="headerLink">
            <a href="#top" onclick="lenis.scrollTo('#top')">
              <span class="headerText">Home</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="headerLink">
            <a href="#About" onclick="lenis.scrollTo('#About')">
              <span class="headerText">About</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="headerLink">
            <a href="#Plugins" onclick="lenis.scrollTo('#Plugins')">
              <span class="headerText">Plugins</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="headerLink">
            <a href="#FAQ" onclick="lenis.scrollTo('#FAQ')">
              <span class="headerText">FAQ</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="headerLink right-li connectButton">
            <a href="#Documentation" onclick="lenis.scrollTo('#Documentation')">
              <span class="headerText">Documentation</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="HomeView" class="hidemee">
      <p id="title">
        <strong>Quokka</strong
        ><br style="display: block; content: ''; margin-top: -4%" />
        <span style="font-size: medium; font-weight: bold"
          >A customizable keystroke launcher with plugins<br
        /></span>
        <span style="display: inline-block">
          <a href="https://github.com/Faeq-F/Quokka/releases/latest">
            <button class="button-64" role="button">
              <span class="text">Download Latest Release</span>
            </button>
          </a>
        </span>
        <span style="display: inline-block">
          <a href="https://github.com/Faeq-F/Quokka">
            <button class="button-64" role="button">
              <span class="text">View Repository</span>
            </button>
          </a> </span
        ><br />
        <span style="position: inherit">
          <input
            id="themeSlider"
            class="slider__input"
            type="range"
            role="slider"
            value="288"
            min="0"
            max="360"
            id="hue"
          />
          <input
            id="themeSwitch"
            class="switch__input"
            type="checkbox"
            role="switch"
          />
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <img
      src="Resources/scrollDown.gif"
      id="HomeScrollImg"
    />
    <div id="About">
      <div class="ag-timeline_title-box" data-aos="fade-down">
        <div class="ag-timeline_tagline">What is this?</div>
        <div class="ag-timeline_title">About Quokka</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card aboutCard" data-aos="fade-down">
        <p>
          Quokka is an extremely customizable keystroke launcher for Windows.
          <br />
          <br />
          Quokka has a plugin-architecture, open to third parties. Through this,
          Quokka will have a large number of features, like color conversion,
          translation, web search, Unicode character search, and much more!
          Please see the
          <a href="#Documentation" onclick="lenis.scrollTo('#Documentation')"
            >Documentation</a
          >
          for all (official) planned plugins. If you do not see a plugin you
          wish to have, maybe start a discussion over
          <a href="https://github.com/Faeq-F/Quokka/discussions">here</a>, or
          create it yourself.
          <br />
          <br />
          Quokka was designed to replace the need for your ugly start menu, task
          bar and any other clunky applications you currently use to add
          functionality to your system. For example, it can replace your start
          menu by allowing you to launch all of your desired applications and
          shortcuts, and replace windows search through plugins like Everything,
          calculator, wikipedia, etc.
          <br />
        </p>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <br />
        <div>
          <a href="https://github.com">
            <img
              align="center"
              margin="10px auto"
              src="https://img.shields.io/static/v1?label=&amp;message=GitHub&amp;color=181717&amp;logo=GitHub&amp;logoColor=FFFFFF"
              alt="Github"
            />
          </a>
          <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language">
            <img
              align="center"
              margin="10px auto"
              src="https://img.shields.io/static/v1?label=&message=UML&color=FABD14&logo=uml&logoColor=FFFFFF"
              alt="UML"
            />
          </a>

          <a href="https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/">
            <img
              align="center"
              margin="10px auto"
              src="https://img.shields.io/static/v1?label=&message=.NET&color=512BD4&logo=dotnet&logoColor=FFFFFF"
              alt="dotnet"
            />
          </a>
          <a
            href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/overview/?view=netdesktop-7.0"
          >
            <img
              align="center"
              margin="10px auto"
              src="https://img.shields.io/static/v1?label=&message=WPF&color=0078D4&logo=windows&logoColor=FFFFFF"
              alt="WPF"
            />
          </a>
          <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/">
            <img
              align="center"
              margin="10px auto"
              src="https://img.shields.io/static/v1?label=&message=C%23&color=512BD4&logo=csharp&logoColor=FFFFFF"
              alt="C&#35;"
            />
          </a>
          <a
            href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/xaml/?view=netdesktop-7.0"
          >
            <img
              align="center"
              margin="10px auto"
              src="https://img.shields.io/static/v1?label=&message=xaml&color=0C54C2&logo=xaml&logoColor=FFFFFF"
              alt="xaml"
            />
          </a>

          <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/">
            <img
              align="center"
              margin="10px auto"
              src="https://img.shields.io/static/v1?label=&amp;message=PowerShell&amp;color=5391FE&amp;logo=PowerShell&amp;logoColor=FFFFFF"
              alt="Powershell"
            />
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.json.org/json-en.html">
            <img
              align="center"
              margin="10px auto"
              src="https://img.shields.io/static/v1?label=&amp;message=JSON&amp;color=000000&amp;logo=JSON&amp;logoColor=FFFFFF"
              alt="JSON"
            />
          </a>

          <a href="https://code.visualstudio.com/">
            <img
              align="center"
              margin="10px auto"
              src="https://img.shields.io/static/v1?label=&amp;message=Visual Studio Code&amp;color=007ACC&amp;logo=Visual Studio Code&amp;logoColor=FFFFFF"
              alt="visual studio code"
            />
          </a>
          <a href="https://visualstudio.microsoft.com">
            <img
              align="center"
              margin="10px auto"
              src="https://img.shields.io/static/v1?label=&message=Visual%20Studio&color=5C2D91&logo=visualstudio&logoColor=FFFFFF"
              alt="visualstudio"
            />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Plugins">
      <section>
        <aside>
          <div class="ag-timeline_title-box" data-aos="fade-up-right">
            <div class="ag-timeline_tagline">What features?</div>
            <div class="ag-timeline_title">Plugins</div>
          </div>
          <div class="card" data-aos="fade-up-right">
            <p class="PortfolioWorkHeader" style="font-size: 1.17em">
              Screenshots for selected plugin:
            </p>
            <div id="PluginScreenshotsGrid" data-lenis-prevent></div>
            <img
              src="Resources/scrollDown.gif"
              id="PortfolioScrollImg"
            />
          </div>
        </aside>

        <div class="content" data-aos="fade-up-left">
          <p class="PortfolioWorkHeader">Recognized plugins:</p>
          <div style="text-align: center">
            <div class="ProjectCard">
              <p class="PluginName">Installed Apps</p>
              <p class="PluginDesc">
                Allows the launching of apps installed on the system
              </p>
              <div class="PluginButtonGroup">
                <a
                  class="SiteButton"
                  title="Visit site"
                  href="https://github.com/Faeq-F/Quokka"
                >
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    height="16"
                    width="20"
                    viewBox="0 0 640 512"
                  >
                    <!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc.-->
                    <path
                      fill="var(--primary)"
                      d="M579.8 267.7c56.5-56.5 56.5-148 0-204.5c-50-50-128.8-56.5-186.3-15.4l-1.6 1.1c-14.4 10.3-17.7 30.3-7.4 44.6s30.3 17.7 44.6 7.4l1.6-1.1c32.1-22.9 76-19.3 103.8 8.6c31.5 31.5 31.5 82.5 0 114L422.3 334.8c-31.5 31.5-82.5 31.5-114 0c-27.9-27.9-31.5-71.8-8.6-103.8l1.1-1.6c10.3-14.4 6.9-34.4-7.4-44.6s-34.4-6.9-44.6 7.4l-1.1 1.6C206.5 251.2 213 330 263 380c56.5 56.5 148 56.5 204.5 0L579.8 267.7zM60.2 244.3c-56.5 56.5-56.5 148 0 204.5c50 50 128.8 56.5 186.3 15.4l1.6-1.1c14.4-10.3 17.7-30.3 7.4-44.6s-30.3-17.7-44.6-7.4l-1.6 1.1c-32.1 22.9-76 19.3-103.8-8.6C74 372 74 321 105.5 289.5L217.7 177.2c31.5-31.5 82.5-31.5 114 0c27.9 27.9 31.5 71.8 8.6 103.9l-1.1 1.6c-10.3 14.4-6.9 34.4 7.4 44.6s34.4 6.9 44.6-7.4l1.1-1.6C433.5 260.8 427 182 377 132c-56.5-56.5-148-56.5-204.5 0L60.2 244.3z"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </a>
                <p class="DeveloperName">Developed by Faeq</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ProjectCard">
              <p class="PluginName">Portable Apps</p>
              <p class="PluginDesc">
                Allows the launching of portable apps<br />(apps not installed
                on the system)
              </p>
              <div class="PluginButtonGroup">
                <a
                  class="SiteButton"
                  title="Visit site"
                  href="https://github.com/Faeq-F/Quokka"
                >
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    height="16"
                    width="20"
                    viewBox="0 0 640 512"
                  >
                    <!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc.-->
                    <path
                      fill="var(--primary)"
                      d="M579.8 267.7c56.5-56.5 56.5-148 0-204.5c-50-50-128.8-56.5-186.3-15.4l-1.6 1.1c-14.4 10.3-17.7 30.3-7.4 44.6s30.3 17.7 44.6 7.4l1.6-1.1c32.1-22.9 76-19.3 103.8 8.6c31.5 31.5 31.5 82.5 0 114L422.3 334.8c-31.5 31.5-82.5 31.5-114 0c-27.9-27.9-31.5-71.8-8.6-103.8l1.1-1.6c10.3-14.4 6.9-34.4-7.4-44.6s-34.4-6.9-44.6 7.4l-1.1 1.6C206.5 251.2 213 330 263 380c56.5 56.5 148 56.5 204.5 0L579.8 267.7zM60.2 244.3c-56.5 56.5-56.5 148 0 204.5c50 50 128.8 56.5 186.3 15.4l1.6-1.1c14.4-10.3 17.7-30.3 7.4-44.6s-30.3-17.7-44.6-7.4l-1.6 1.1c-32.1 22.9-76 19.3-103.8-8.6C74 372 74 321 105.5 289.5L217.7 177.2c31.5-31.5 82.5-31.5 114 0c27.9 27.9 31.5 71.8 8.6 103.9l-1.1 1.6c-10.3 14.4-6.9 34.4 7.4 44.6s34.4 6.9 44.6-7.4l1.1-1.6C433.5 260.8 427 182 377 132c-56.5-56.5-148-56.5-204.5 0L60.2 244.3z"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </a>
                <p class="DeveloperName">Developed by Faeq</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ProjectCard">
              <p class="PluginName">Everything</p>
              <p class="PluginDesc">
                Allows searching through files and folders on the computer -
                requires the
                <a
                  href="https://www.voidtools.com/"
                  style="font-style: oblique"
                >
                  Everything
                </a>
                service to be running
              </p>
              <div class="PluginButtonGroup">
                <a
                  class="SiteButton"
                  title="Visit site"
                  href="https://github.com/Faeq-F/Quokka"
                >
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    height="16"
                    width="20"
                    viewBox="0 0 640 512"
                  >
                    <!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc.-->
                    <path
                      fill="var(--primary)"
                      d="M579.8 267.7c56.5-56.5 56.5-148 0-204.5c-50-50-128.8-56.5-186.3-15.4l-1.6 1.1c-14.4 10.3-17.7 30.3-7.4 44.6s30.3 17.7 44.6 7.4l1.6-1.1c32.1-22.9 76-19.3 103.8 8.6c31.5 31.5 31.5 82.5 0 114L422.3 334.8c-31.5 31.5-82.5 31.5-114 0c-27.9-27.9-31.5-71.8-8.6-103.8l1.1-1.6c10.3-14.4 6.9-34.4-7.4-44.6s-34.4-6.9-44.6 7.4l-1.1 1.6C206.5 251.2 213 330 263 380c56.5 56.5 148 56.5 204.5 0L579.8 267.7zM60.2 244.3c-56.5 56.5-56.5 148 0 204.5c50 50 128.8 56.5 186.3 15.4l1.6-1.1c14.4-10.3 17.7-30.3 7.4-44.6s-30.3-17.7-44.6-7.4l-1.6 1.1c-32.1 22.9-76 19.3-103.8-8.6C74 372 74 321 105.5 289.5L217.7 177.2c31.5-31.5 82.5-31.5 114 0c27.9 27.9 31.5 71.8 8.6 103.9l-1.1 1.6c-10.3 14.4-6.9 34.4 7.4 44.6s34.4 6.9 44.6-7.4l1.1-1.6C433.5 260.8 427 182 377 132c-56.5-56.5-148-56.5-204.5 0L60.2 244.3z"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </a>
                <p class="DeveloperName">Developed by Faeq</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ProjectCard">
              <p class="PluginName">Power Commands</p>
              <p class="PluginDesc">
                Allows the execution of power settings like logout, lock, sleep,
                shutdown, etc.
              </p>
              <div class="PluginButtonGroup">
                <a
                  class="SiteButton"
                  title="Visit site"
                  href="https://github.com/Faeq-F/Quokka"
                >
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    height="16"
                    width="20"
                    viewBox="0 0 640 512"
                  >
                    <!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc.-->
                    <path
                      fill="var(--primary)"
                      d="M579.8 267.7c56.5-56.5 56.5-148 0-204.5c-50-50-128.8-56.5-186.3-15.4l-1.6 1.1c-14.4 10.3-17.7 30.3-7.4 44.6s30.3 17.7 44.6 7.4l1.6-1.1c32.1-22.9 76-19.3 103.8 8.6c31.5 31.5 31.5 82.5 0 114L422.3 334.8c-31.5 31.5-82.5 31.5-114 0c-27.9-27.9-31.5-71.8-8.6-103.8l1.1-1.6c10.3-14.4 6.9-34.4-7.4-44.6s-34.4-6.9-44.6 7.4l-1.1 1.6C206.5 251.2 213 330 263 380c56.5 56.5 148 56.5 204.5 0L579.8 267.7zM60.2 244.3c-56.5 56.5-56.5 148 0 204.5c50 50 128.8 56.5 186.3 15.4l1.6-1.1c14.4-10.3 17.7-30.3 7.4-44.6s-30.3-17.7-44.6-7.4l-1.6 1.1c-32.1 22.9-76 19.3-103.8-8.6C74 372 74 321 105.5 289.5L217.7 177.2c31.5-31.5 82.5-31.5 114 0c27.9 27.9 31.5 71.8 8.6 103.9l-1.1 1.6c-10.3 14.4-6.9 34.4 7.4 44.6s34.4 6.9 44.6-7.4l1.1-1.6C433.5 260.8 427 182 377 132c-56.5-56.5-148-56.5-204.5 0L60.2 244.3z"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </a>
                <p class="DeveloperName">Developed by Faeq</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ProjectCard">
              <p class="PluginName">Calculator</p>
              <p class="PluginDesc">
                Allows the calculation of mathematical expressions
              </p>
              <div class="PluginButtonGroup">
                <a
                  class="SiteButton"
                  title="Visit site"
                  href="https://github.com/Faeq-F/Quokka"
                >
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    height="16"
                    width="20"
                    viewBox="0 0 640 512"
                  >
                    <!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc.-->
                    <path
                      fill="var(--primary)"
                      d="M579.8 267.7c56.5-56.5 56.5-148 0-204.5c-50-50-128.8-56.5-186.3-15.4l-1.6 1.1c-14.4 10.3-17.7 30.3-7.4 44.6s30.3 17.7 44.6 7.4l1.6-1.1c32.1-22.9 76-19.3 103.8 8.6c31.5 31.5 31.5 82.5 0 114L422.3 334.8c-31.5 31.5-82.5 31.5-114 0c-27.9-27.9-31.5-71.8-8.6-103.8l1.1-1.6c10.3-14.4 6.9-34.4-7.4-44.6s-34.4-6.9-44.6 7.4l-1.1 1.6C206.5 251.2 213 330 263 380c56.5 56.5 148 56.5 204.5 0L579.8 267.7zM60.2 244.3c-56.5 56.5-56.5 148 0 204.5c50 50 128.8 56.5 186.3 15.4l1.6-1.1c14.4-10.3 17.7-30.3 7.4-44.6s-30.3-17.7-44.6-7.4l-1.6 1.1c-32.1 22.9-76 19.3-103.8-8.6C74 372 74 321 105.5 289.5L217.7 177.2c31.5-31.5 82.5-31.5 114 0c27.9 27.9 31.5 71.8 8.6 103.9l-1.1 1.6c-10.3 14.4-6.9 34.4 7.4 44.6s34.4 6.9 44.6-7.4l1.1-1.6C433.5 260.8 427 182 377 132c-56.5-56.5-148-56.5-204.5 0L60.2 244.3z"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </a>
                <p class="DeveloperName">Developed by Faeq</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ProjectCard">
              <p class="PluginName">English Dictionary</p>
              <p class="PluginDesc">
                Allows the viewing of denotations for words in the English (US)
                language
              </p>
              <div class="PluginButtonGroup">
                <a
                  class="SiteButton"
                  title="Visit site"
                  href="https://github.com/Faeq-F/Quokka"
                >
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    height="16"
                    width="20"
                    viewBox="0 0 640 512"
                  >
                    <!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc.-->
                    <path
                      fill="var(--primary)"
                      d="M579.8 267.7c56.5-56.5 56.5-148 0-204.5c-50-50-128.8-56.5-186.3-15.4l-1.6 1.1c-14.4 10.3-17.7 30.3-7.4 44.6s30.3 17.7 44.6 7.4l1.6-1.1c32.1-22.9 76-19.3 103.8 8.6c31.5 31.5 31.5 82.5 0 114L422.3 334.8c-31.5 31.5-82.5 31.5-114 0c-27.9-27.9-31.5-71.8-8.6-103.8l1.1-1.6c10.3-14.4 6.9-34.4-7.4-44.6s-34.4-6.9-44.6 7.4l-1.1 1.6C206.5 251.2 213 330 263 380c56.5 56.5 148 56.5 204.5 0L579.8 267.7zM60.2 244.3c-56.5 56.5-56.5 148 0 204.5c50 50 128.8 56.5 186.3 15.4l1.6-1.1c14.4-10.3 17.7-30.3 7.4-44.6s-30.3-17.7-44.6-7.4l-1.6 1.1c-32.1 22.9-76 19.3-103.8-8.6C74 372 74 321 105.5 289.5L217.7 177.2c31.5-31.5 82.5-31.5 114 0c27.9 27.9 31.5 71.8 8.6 103.9l-1.1 1.6c-10.3 14.4-6.9 34.4 7.4 44.6s34.4 6.9 44.6-7.4l1.1-1.6C433.5 260.8 427 182 377 132c-56.5-56.5-148-56.5-204.5 0L60.2 244.3z"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </a>
                <p class="DeveloperName">Developed by Faeq</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <p style="color: var(--primary)">Please support all developers!</p>
          </div>

          <h2 style="color: transparent">Title 1</h2>
          <h4 style="color: transparent">Subheading</h4>
          <p style="color: transparent">Text</p>
          <h4 style="color: transparent">Subheading</h4>
          <p style="color: transparent">Text</p>
          <h4 style="color: transparent">Subheading</h4>
          <p style="color: transparent">Text</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>

    <div id="FAQ">
      <div class="ag-timeline_title-box" data-aos="fade-down">
        <div class="ag-timeline_tagline">I have a question!</div>
        <div class="ag-timeline_title">Frequently asked Questions</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card aboutCard" data-aos="fade-down">
        <p>
          Quokka is an extremely customizable keystroke launcher for Windows. It
          has a plugin-architecture, open to third parties.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer id="Documentation">
      <div id="DocumentationCard" class="ContactCard" data-aos="fade-down">
        <div id="container-stars" style="top: 0; left: 0">
          <div id="stars"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-timeline_title-box ConnectTitleBox">
          <div
            class="ag-timeline_tagline ConnectTagline"
            style="font-weight: bold; font-size: x-large !important"
          >
            <div id="DocsHeader">
              <button id="FillPageButton" title="Fill Page"></button>
              <button id="FullscreenButton" title="Fullscreen"></button>
              <button id="DocsHeaderButton">Documentation</button>
            </div>
            <div id="DocsNav" data-lenis-prevent>
              <ul>
                <li><button>Installation</button></li>
                <li><button>How to use</button></li>
                <ul>
                  <li><button>Tray task</button></li>
                  <li><button>Plugins</button></li>
                  <li><button>Special commands</button></li>
                </ul>
                <li><button>Settings</button></li>
                <ul>
                  <li><button>Themes</button></li>
                  <li><button>Defaults</button></li>
                </ul>
                <li><button>Building the app</button></li>
                <li><button>Writing a plugin</button></li>
                <ul>
                  <li><button>Creating a new item type</button></li>
                  <li><button>Creating a context pane</button></li>
                  <li><button>Creating the plugin</button></li>
                </ul>
                <li><button>FAQ by Developers</button></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="DocsContent" data-lenis-prevent></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <div id="bottom">
      <p style="color: transparent">.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="cursor"></div>
    <div class="cursor2"></div>

    <script src="scripts/cursor.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script>
      AOS.init();
    </script>
    <script src="scripts/Gallery.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/header.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ScrollFade.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/HueRotate.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Docs.js"></script>
    <script>
      function themeChangeHandler() {
        var queryString = "?reload=" + new Date().getTime();
        $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').each(function () {
          this.href = this.href.replace(/\?.*|$/, queryString);
        });
      }
      document
        .querySelector("#themeSwitch")
        .addEventListener("change", themeChangeHandler);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You also had a missing file and a wrongly named file as well. Double check your file names (be careful with casing).

After fixing these issues, your website will work fine both on localhost and on Github Pages.

Here's a [repository](https://github.com/creme332/quokka-test) that I set up to show your website working correctly. The corresponding website is at: https://creme332.github.io/quokka-test/:

[image]

There are still some styling issues that you will have to fix but there are no 404 errors in console.